# Laravel 10 basic localization not working

Tags: laravel, localization, locale, translation, laravel-artisan

Can somebody help me run the basic localization for Laravel 10? I have followed guides, but localization still does not work.

I run command:

```
php artisan lang:publish
```

This created folder with files that I simplified creating only one file, `lang/en/messages.php`. Content of `messages.php`:

```
<?php

return [
  'my_string' => 'My localized string',  
];
```

I have created middleware `LanguageManager`:

```
class LanguageManager
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        if (\Session::get("locale") != null) {
            App::setLocale(\Session::get("locale"));
        } else {
            \Session::put("locale", "en");
            App::setLocale(\Session::get("locale"));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I have added this file to `Kernel`:

```
 protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            ...
            \App\Http\Middleware\LanguageManager::class,
        ],
```

In my controller, I have added following lines to `index` function:

```
\App::setLocale('en');
session()->put('locale', 'en');
```

And finally, in my `blade` file:

```
...
<span>{{ __('messages.my_string') }}</span>
...
```

I have also run command `php artisan cache:clear`. However, the app still shows 'my_string' instead of 'My localized string'.

Can somebody advise how to solve this? I think official guides should be more descriptive to help new developers to create basic functional examples. Thank you very much.

Comment: I've not yet done much with localizations myself, but in the blade file try with: `'messages.my_string'`?

Comment: I have tried `{{ __('messages.my_string') }}` as well, but it does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

Basic dot notation syntax for getting translation string from language file is `filename.key`, so in this case, proper function call would be `__('messages.my_string')`.

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/localization#retrieving-translation-strings

Comment: I have tried that as well, `{{ __('messages.my_string') }}` does not work either.